# Kumo WordCloud avoid skipping

Tags: java, word-cloud, tag-cloud

Been enjoying using WordCloud generator written by (https://github.com/kennycason/kumo) and its very effective. However, just noticed it can exclude high scoring words during the collision phase.

It seems to skip less words if I use CollisionMode.PIXEL_PERFECT and skips more words if I use CollisionMode.RECTANGLE. But just wondering if anyone knows if there's a setting to override this and force that all words be placed regardless, even if they had to be placed at the end of the cycle?

Tried using Kumo WordCloud by Kenny Cason (https://github.com/kennycason/kumo). Tried out using CollisionMode.PIXEL_PERFECT and CollisionMode.RECTANGLE to try improve not skipping words